# Scrapy - use "normalize-space" with a list of items

Tags: python, scrapy

Trying to remove escape symbols and spaces from html list.
I'm using normalize-space() but was not able to apply it to whole list.
I'm testing my code using scrapy shell

`scrapy shell https://universalmotors.ru/boardmotors/suzuki/suzuki-df-4-s/`

```html
<tr itemprop="additionalProperty" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/PropertyValue">
              <td class="label_table" itemprop="name">Мощность двигателя (л.с.)</td>
              <td class="value_table">
                <span itemprop="value">4</span>
              </td>
            </tr>
<tr itemprop="additionalProperty" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/PropertyValue">
              <td class="label_table" itemprop="name">Тип масла в двигателе</td>
              <td class="value_table">
                <span itemprop="value">10W-30 10W-40</span>
              </td>
            </tr>
```

Here what I tried

`[item.normalize-space() for item in response.xpath('//tr[@itemprop="additionalProperty"]').extract()]`

But i'm getting an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<console>", line 1, in <listcomp>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'normalize'
```

It is only working for

```
[item.strip() for item in response.xpath('//tr[@itemprop="additionalProperty"]').extract()]
```

then I get folowing

```
['<tr itemprop="additionalProperty" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/PropertyValue">\n              <td class="label_table" itemprop="name">Мощность двигателя (л.с.)</td>\n              <td class="value_table">\n                <span itemprop="value">4</span>\n              </td>\n            </tr>', '<tr itemprop="additionalProperty" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/PropertyValue">\n              <td class="label_table" itemprop="name">Тип масла в двигателе</td>\n              <td class="value_table">\n
```

My goal is to get flowing:

```
Мощность двигателя (л.с.) 4
Тип масла в двигателе 10W-30 10W-40
Объем масла в двигателе 700
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[normalize-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space) is a XPath function, not a Python function or a method of a Python object. So you need to use it in the XPath expression like this:

```
for item in response.xpath('//tr[@itemprop="additionalProperty"]'):
    yield {
        'name': item.xpath('normalize-space(./*[@itemprop="name"])').extract_first(),
        'value': item.xpath('normalize-space(./*[@itemprop="value"])').extract_first()
    }
```

Comment: Great, it worked with a slight modification,  `for item in response.xpath('//tr[@itemprop="additionalProperty"]'):
            yield {
                'name': item.xpath('normalize-space(./*[@class="label_table"])').extract_first(),
                'value': item.xpath('normalize-space(./*[@class="value_table"])').extract_first()
            }`

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using [html-text](https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/html-text) instead of XPath’s [`normalize-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space) to achieve your goal.

```
>>> from html_text import extract_text
>>> extract_text('''
... <tr itemprop="additionalProperty" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/PropertyValue">
...               <td class="label_table" itemprop="name">Мощность двигателя (л.с.)</td>
...               <td class="value_table">
...                 <span itemprop="value">4</span>
...               </td>
...             </tr>
... <tr itemprop="additionalProperty" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/PropertyValue">
...               <td class="label_table" itemprop="name">Тип масла в двигателе</td>
...               <td class="value_table">
...                 <span itemprop="value">10W-30 10W-40</span>
...               </td>
...             </tr>
... ''')
'Мощность двигателя (л.с.) 4\nТип масла в двигателе 10W-30 10W-40'
```